# Linkedin Api Integration for get company post

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

Currently I am woking on likedin Api Integration . I want to get top 4 post of a public company from likedin .It seems like its little tricky . I want to implemnet this in C# code . Anyone have idea ?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: I am trying to use Linkedin API directly. but there is so many authentications integration required . So I am looking for some wrapper class to integrate it .

Comment: try this one https://github.com/SparkleNetworks/LinkedInNET